# How to use remote file URL's with MediaFileUpload from Google Python Youtube API

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api

When i invoke MediaFileUpload in python with the (apiclient.http) GOOGLE API:

```
media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
```

It works with a local file on the drive:

```
options.file = "/www/var/videos/video.mp4"
```

But when I try to use a remote file lets say on a CDN like amazon - it fails.

```
options.file = "http://xxx-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/video.mp4"
```

Is there an option to use MediaFileUpload with remote files that I havent found without having to pull the remote file down , uploaded it via GOOGLE Api and then delete it?

Comment: Had any luck with uploading via url?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download the remote file to a `io.BytesIO()` object (`import io`), it will be only in program memory without need to save it on computer. Next, you can create the object

```
MediaIoBaseUpload( io.BytesIO(), mime_type='<file_type>')
```

(it's a parent object for `MediaFileUpload` and it's in `googleapiclient.http` just like `MediaFileUpload`).
Now you can pass this object to `media_body` like `MediaFileUpload`.